XBox Wireless Controller Not Working Ubuntu 24.04
I have an XBox Wireless Controller, model #1914. I can get it to connect over bluetooth but it doesn't show up as a joystick in jstest or steam.  It doesn't show up at all as a usb device in, say, lsusb.  I've tried install xpadneo but that didn't seem to do anything.
